# How to enable WMI Provider MSCluster on MS Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, failover, wmi

I have successfully set up a failover cluster on Microsoft Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition. Now I want to talk to the MSCluster WMI Provider on said server. WMI Queries to e.g. CIMV2 successed. But queries like

```
select * from MSCluster_ResourceGroup where MSCluster_ResourceGroup.Name=\"testserver\"
```

fail with "Access denied". I am using a domain admin account.

Do I have to enable the MSCluster WMI Provider? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using imprsonate security? What language or scripting are you using?

Comment: The program that sends the WMI query is running as domain admin. I guess it must be, otherwise IMHO I could not connect to classes in root\CIMV2 either. The programming language is C#/.NET - The weird thing is, that it works fine on a server 2003.

When using a WMI Query Tool the tool does not even list any classes in root\MSCluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see [this](http://blogs.technet.com/brad_rutkowski/archive/2008/09/08/getting-access-denied-when-trying-to-query-root-mscluster-namespace-remotely-against-windows-2008.aspx) blog article? Seems very similar to your issue.

The mscluster namespace requires encryption, so to connect to it you need to have a PacketPrivacy authentication level on your query.